# Connecting to a remote SQL named instance with named pipe

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2019, network, protocol

I found out that when I connect to a remote SQL named instance (ServerA\instanceA) from SSMS installed on ServerB, it does connect without error, but it uses the Named Pipe protocol.

I found that out when I noticed that the SQL named instance port (50002) was blocked by the Firewall.

From SSMS (on serverB), I get an error when I try to connect to ServerA,50002 but it succeeded when I connect to ServerA\InstanceA.

I googled it, but wasn't able to find any good documentation explaining why it works.

I checked and I didn't see any alias or any particular configuration for ServerA.

If you could help me understand how (and why) it works, I would appreciate.

Comment: Is the named instance the only instance installed on that server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the named instance TCP port 50002 was blocked, [port 445 is used for named pipes (SMB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503234/sql-server-ports-445-and-1433) and is apparently allowed by the firewall.

The SqlClient driver tries TCP/IP first and then falls back and attempts named pipes when the TCP connection fails. This is called out in the [Client Protocols Properties doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/client-protocols-properties-order-tab?view=sql-server-ver16). That's why one often sees a reference to named pipes in the error message when a connection fails.

IIRC, older drivers tried named pipes first and TCP/IP only when that failed.